# Dynamically Update C# variable with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

The code below displays images in images list **which have** "Airport" value in imagesublist.

For example **imagesublist** look like this:
{[image1,Airport],[image2,Retail]}

And the code below only shows image1; Not sure this is the best way but it works.

.aspx file

```
    <ul class="links">
    <%for (int i = 0; i < images.Count(); i++)
     { 
      if(imagesublist.Count(item => item.Contains(images[i]) 
                                    && item.Contains("Airport")) > 0) {%>          
    <li><a href="#"><img id="gridimages" src="<%=realPath + images[i]%>"/></a></li>
    <%}
}%>
    </ul>
//images and imagesublist are list, generated in codebehind C# and works fine.
```

**Now My Question is:**

I already have a variable in jquery called **type** which stores the values of input checkboxs.
How can I replace the static "Airport" with **type** variable generated in js.

I know I can call functions like `item.Contains(Getitem())` or anything similar. but since my if statement is wrapped in <%%> I can only use C#.

I have also tried something like this and it didn't work:

```
    <ul class="links">
    <%for (int i = 0; i < images.Count(); i++)
     { 
      if(imagesublist.Count(item => item.Contains(images[i]) 
                                    && item.Contains("%>Gettypes()<%")) > 0) {%>          
    <li><a href="#"><img id="gridimages" src="<%=realPath + images[i]%>"/></a></li>
    <%}
}%>
    </ul>
```

Is there any logical way to also call a js function in middle of <% %> tags?

Comment: Code within `<% %>` tags are run at the server before being sent and displayed to the user.  There is no way for JS to modify it at that point.  You'll have to make a new round trip to the server with the type information.

Answer (score 0):

It can not be changed because `<% anyobjectvalue %>` is a server side object and rendered on page as text.